# Find specific field in mongoose and validate value of it with express validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, express-validator

I have a mongoose schema that has an array contains an enum field and value for each enum , I want to for example check that if the enum is nationalId , check the value field of it .
How can I do this with express-validator
Here`s my schema:

```
fields: {
  type: [
    {
      _id: false,
      name: {
        type: String,
        enum: [
          "name",
          "nationalId"
        ],
        required: true,
      },
      value: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

and here is postman json request:

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "nationalId",
            "value": "454643"
        },
}
```

here`s my current validation but not work(I use it as middleware and put it before the endpoint in my route) :

```
exports.isNationalNumber = body("fields.*.name.nationalId")
.exists()
.withMessage({ message: "not valid", errorCode: "1" })
.bail()
.trim()
.matches(/^\d{10}$/)
.withMessage({ message: "not valid", errorCode: "2" })
.bail();
```

I want to check that if fields name is "nationalId" check the value of it.